If I pass a const char* to std::vector<std::string>'s push_back, will it be copied or moved?
In this code (using C++17), will "abc" be used to create a std::string temporary object and then copied into letters by push_back, or will it be moved ?
Is it more efficient to use push_back or emplace_back in this circumstance?
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> letters;
    letters.push_back("abc");
}


Literal constant strings are really arrays of (constant) characters, and usually stored in memory that is not writeable. This array itself can't be moved. But the temporary std::string object that is created in the call can be moved, but that string is independent of the literal string you pass as an argument. With that said,  emplace_back is probably better anyway.

The foundation issue here is that a char-string literal needs to be converted to std::string before it can be put into the std::vector, because you declared a std::vector<std::string>.  This conversion will take place first, then the new std::string will be placed into the std::vector.

Beware sloppiness with the word "it". In your title, you ask "will [the const char*] be copied or moved?" while the question itself asks "will [the temporary object] be moved?" Those are two rather different questions. (For the former, moving a pointer is the same as copying it, so you probably meant the pointed-to data instead of the pointer. However, the copy of the data occurs when the temporary is created, so still before what is asked in the question's body.)

vector::push_back() has an overload that accepts an rvalue, so the temporary std::string will be moved and not copied.
If you use vector::emplace_back() instead, the temporary std::string will be avoided altogether.

To go a step further, I would avoid using push_back() as much as possible. emplace_back() is simply faster since it avoids any unnecessary copying or moving. However, you might prefer push_back() over emplace_back() if the object is already constructed and moving the data is faster than re-constructing.

@SetupWizard "if the object is already constructed and moving the data is faster than re-constructing" -- You can move an already constructed object into emplace_back just as easily as moving it into push_back, utilizing the same move constructor. Better reasons for preferring push_back can be found in Why would I ever use push_back instead of emplace_back?
